# How to prove that a decomposition into BCNF which is both dependency preserving and loss-less doesn't exist?

Tags: database, database-design, schema, database-schema, database-normalization

How to prove that a decomposition into BCNF which is both dependency preserving and loss-less doesn't exist for a specific schema?
Is there a rule that holds? Or do I need to go through all BCNF possible decompositions?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand the question.  Are you saying that moving from 3NF to BCNF can't be both lossless and dependency preserving? Or are you saying that there are cases where moving from 3NF to BCNF can't?  I am asking because I can think of cases where such a move is lossless and dependency preserving.  So I figure you must be looking at a specific example?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the relation R(ABC) with functional dependencies are {AB→C, C→B}. The candidate keys are {AB, AC} and R is in 3NF, since all attribute of relation is prime attribute.

But, relation R is not in BCNF, since FD {C→B} doesn't satisfy the conditions of BCNF, (i.e., C is not candidate key).

Now, if we want to decompose into BCNF, we loose either FDs.

So, its not possible in this case, hence BCNF is not always achievable.